# math.cos function returning different value than calculator

Tags: python

I have this function that takes in an x value and returns an output y value.

```
def function(x):
    y = math.cos(x**2/2)/(math.log(x+2,2))
    return y
```

When I call the function, I get:

```
print function(1)
>> 0.630929753571
```

But [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos((x)%5E2%2F2)%2Flog(2,x%2B2))%20at%20x%20%3D%201) has the value at x = 1 to be 0.553693

Which is the correct value?

Comment: This could be a radian vs degree issue. Make sure they're using the same units.

Comment: use `/2.0` to get float result - Python 2 rounds result to integer if you divide integer by integer

Comment: Also, are you comparing the Wolfram `cos` results with the results of your entire function? I wouldn't expect them to match then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using Python 2, where the `/` operator does integer division. This would give you the correct answer in Python 3:

```
>>> def f(x):
...   y = math.cos(x**2/2)/(math.log(x+2,2))
...   return y
...
>>> f(1)
0.5536929495121011
```

In Python 3, using the `//` operator, does floor division:

```
>>> def f(x):
...   y = math.cos(x**2//2)/(math.log(x+2,2))
...   return y
...
>>> f(1)
0.6309297535714574
>>>
```

In Python 2, use `y = math.cos(x**2/ 2.0) / (math.log(x+2,2))`

Answer (score 0):

you are dividing an int by another int which is greater: `1 / 2`  and therefore getting the cosine of zero since python 2.7 does not evaluate integer divisions as floating point. Try:

```
def function(x):
    y = math.cos(x ** 2 / 2.0) / (math.log(x + 2, 2))
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 division operator does integer division, unless you tell it it's a float.

If you change to x**2/2.0 you will get the correct answer, like wolfram alfa.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 rounds to integer when you divide integer by integer so use one float number (i.e `2.0`) when you divide to get correct result

```
import math

def function(x):
    y = math.cos(x**2/2.0)/(math.log(x+2,2))
    return y

print function(1)
```